# Pin multi applications to taskbar in multi-thread mode causes hang

Tags: c#

```
try
{
    ChangeImagePathName("explorer.exe");
    PinUnpinTaskbar(tempFilePath, true);
}
finally
{
    RestoreImagePathName();
}
```

Now in my code i have used this segment of code. However it is in **multi-thread** mode. If multi-thread execute this segment of code, my application will hang on the **PinUnpinTaskbar(tempFilePath, true)** function.

Is there any advice?

Comment: So what is this method, i have never seen it before in the whole 25 years i have been writing code

Comment: _"Is there any advice?"_ - yes don't update the UI from a worker thread.  There's a ga-zillion articles on the web

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)